# Adding markers to a layer at runtime

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I would like to use two layers (units, calls) over the streets base map.

I have a timer loop that runs every 30 seconds and I would like to clear the units layer, then add the new unit markers to the unit layer.

```
  var units = new Graphic();  // graphic with units
  var calls = new Graphic();  // graphic with calls


  map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets-navigation-vector"
  });

  view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      latitude: 38.8935,
      longitude: -77.0487
    }
  });


  var unitsLayer = new GraphicsLayer({
    graphics: [units]
  });

  var callsLayer = new GraphicsLayer({
    graphics: [calls]
  });


  map.add(unitsLayer);
  map.add(callsLayer);
```

- Question 1) How do I clear a layer of markers without effecting the other layers?
- Question 2) How do I add a marker to the units layer at run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all the graphics from a GraphicsLayer, call [removeAll()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GraphicsLayer.html#removeAll):

```
unitsLayer.removeAll();
```

To add a marker to a Graphics Layer, first [create a Graphic](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/intro-graphics/index.html). Then call:

```
unitsLayer.add(g); // (where "g" is that graphic you just created
```